# route shows user login page title

Tags: magento2, login, routing, page-title, meta-title

In one Magento `2.2.6` instance something very odd occurs: the meta page title shows

```
<title>Customer Login</title>
```

and the page title in the content also shows `Customer Login` - *even though the route has nothing to to with the customer login!*

The module in question is [omikron/magento2-factfinder](https://github.com/FACT-Finder-Web-Components/magento2-module/) and the route in question is [factfinder/result/index](https://github.com/FACT-Finder-Web-Components/magento2-module/blob/develop/Omikron/Factfinder/view/frontend/layout/factfinder_result_index.xml). Currently the extension does not set its own page title (I've already created a [PR](https://github.com/FACT-Finder-Web-Components/magento2-module/pull/83) for that), but even when you add

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Search Results</title>
        …
    </head>
    <body>
        …
    </body>
</page>
```

the page still shows `<title>Customer Login</title>` in the meta tags - however the page title in the `<body>` will indeed show `Search Results`.

In a second Magento 2.2.6 instance this problem does not occur.

How can this be? What could be the reason why the page title is overridden in such a manner for a particular route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I've seen on Magento 1 before.
I have a hunch that you have a login form displayed in every page.
Something like a popup that appears when you click on the 'login' button, or something like that.
If this is the case, the problem is cause by that login form.
I assume the block class that displays the mini-form is `Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login` or a class that extends it.
This class has a method called `_prepareLayout` which is called automatically for each block before the block is rendered.

For the login class, the method looks like this:

```
/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Customer Login'));
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

This means, that every page that contains this block will get the meta title `Customer Login`.

You have 2 options here (there may be more):
Option 1: the clean way.

Create a class that extends `Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login`. Your new class should contain a single method

```
/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    return $this;
}
```

Then, use this new class in the layout for the mini-login form.

Option 2: quick and dirty.
Same as in option 1, create the same class, then in the `di.xml` file of your module set a preference for the default login block to your new class

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" type="Your\NewClass\Name\Here" />
```

This should work also, but you might lose the meta title on the actual login page.

As a note: this is a magento inconsistency. the login class knows and does too much. It knows details about the context that it should not know.

Comment: You are right! There is indeed a login block present on every page (to show a login overlay, when clicking a "login" button). However, what I do not understand is: why is this problem not occurring on _every_ page? Regular magento routes or routes of other modules do not seem to be affected. Just the custom route from this module.

Comment: maybe for other pages there is a call to `pageConfig->getTitle()->set(...)` done after `_prepareLayout` is executed.

Comment: May be, yeah. Anyway your solution worked (I used option 1) :)